# Unique database column that is connected to another variable

Tags: mysql, sql, string, unique-constraint

In my database I have `1. UserID` and `2. savename` inside `userDisplay`.
I made the `savename` `unique` using

```
ALTER TABLE `userDisplay` ADD UNIQUE( `savename`);
```

but I want the `savename` to be unique only for the users with the same `UserID`.

Example: user with `UserID = 25` creates a `display` with `savename = firstdisplay`, now user with id 25 should not be able to create the same savename, but user with id 45 can.

I have used `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  to update for user with id 25 but this updates too when user 45 uses the same `savename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the `savename` to be unique only for the users with the same `UserID`.

You want uniqueness for the *tuple* of columns. so put both in the unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `userDisplay` ADD UNIQUE(`UserID`, `savename`);
```